How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec(x) \arctan(\cos(x)) \, dx$
How to evaluate$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec(x) \arctan(\cos(x)) \, dx~~?$$
Wolframalpha says the answer is$$\frac{1}{2} \pi \sinh^{-1}(1)$$
I tried taking $\cos(x)=\tan(\theta)$ and $\cos(x)=u$ but both didn't feel like they were going anywhere. Also tried googling but couldn't find it.

$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan^{-1}(\cos(x)) }{\cos (x)}\, dx$$
Using the below integral, we convert it to a double integral,
$$\frac{\tan^{-1}(\cos x)}{\cos x}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+(t\cos x)^2 }\,dt$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+(t\cos x)^2 }\,dt dx\implies \int_0^1\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{1}{1+(t\cos x)^2 }\,dx dt$$
Using the below result,
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+(t\cos x)^2 }\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t^2+1}}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\sinh^{-1}(1)$$
Needless to say, the above integral is a well-known standard integral

If you want to understand how that result was derived,
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+(t\cos x)^2
 }\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
Rewrite the (indefinite) integral as
$$\int \frac{\sec^2 (x)}{\sec^2 (x) +t^2 }\,dx\implies \int
\frac{\sec^2 (x)}{1+\tan^2(x)+t^2 }\,dx$$
$$\int \frac{\sec^2 (x)}{1+\tan^2(x)+t^2
 }\,dx\underset{\tan(x)=z}\implies \int
\frac{1}{z^2+(\sqrt{1+t^2})^2}\,dz$$
You're once again back to solving standard well known integrals, put
the bounds and you shall prove that result


Using a parameter (It is going to be the same thing done above, "Feynmann technique")
We can generalize this,
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan^{-1}(a\cos(x)) }{\cos (x)}\, dx\underset{x=\frac{\pi}{2}-x}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan^{-1}(a\sin(x)) }{\sin(x)}\, dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\cos(x)} \frac{\cos(x)}{1+(a\cos(x))^2}\, dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \frac{1}{1+(a\cos(x))^2}\, dx$$
Using the above derived result, we get
$$I'(a)=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+a^2}}\implies I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\sinh^{-1}(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln|a+\sqrt{1+a^2}|$$
